# Changing the value of the original string using a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I am attempting to change the value of an original string by changing a pointer.

Say I have:

```
char **stringO = (char**) malloc (sizeof(char*));
*stringO = (char*) malloc (17);    
char stringOne[17] = "a" ;
char stringTwo[17] = "b";
char stringThree[17] = "c";
char newStr[17] = "d";
strcpy(*stringO, stringOne);
strcpy(*stringO, stringTwo);
strcpy(*stringO, stringThree);
//change stringOne to newStr using stringO??
```

How can I change `stringOne`so its the same as `newStr` using the pointer `stringO`?

edit: I guess the question was rather unclear. i want it to modify the latest string that `*strcpy` was copied from. So if `strcpy(*stringO, stringThree);` was last called, it will modify `stringThree`, `strcpy(*stringO, stringTwo);` then `string Two` etc.

Comment: You shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: @chris ([explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858))

Comment: @H2CO3 the other answers on that thread point to good reasons to include the cast

Comment: @gta0004 There are reasons for including the cast. There may even be some good reasons. But they can't be good enough. If you are writing C code, you must not cast the return value, as explained by unwind in the answer I linked to. Basically, nothing but "you can compile your code as C++" *could be* the only valid reason for the typecast - but you know, no sane programmer tries to compile C code as C++ because they are different and very distinct languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want it to modify the **latest** string that `strcpy` was copied from. So if `strcpy( ( *stringO ), stringThree );` was last called, it will modify `stringThree`, `strcpy( (*stringO ), stringTwo );` then `stringTwo` etc.

It is not possible to do this with your approach since you are making a **copy** of the string by using `strcpy` -- not pointing to blocks of memory. To achieve your goal I would do the following:

```
char *stringO = NULL;

char stringOne[ 17 ] = "a";
char stringTwo[ 17 ] = "b";
char stringThree[ 17 ] = "c";
char newStr[ 17 ] = "d";

stringO = stringOne; // Points to the block of memory where stringOne is stored.
stringO = stringTwo; // Points to the block of memory where stringTwo is stored.
stringO = stringThree; // Points to the block of memory where stringThree is stored.

strcpy( stringO, newStr ); // Mutates stringOne to be the same string as newStr.
```

... note that I am mutating (updating) where `stringO` points to, not copying a string into it. This will allow you to mutate the values in the blocks of memory that stringO points as (which is consequently where the latest `stringXXX` is stored) -- as requested.

Comment: yes latest, that was what I was going for. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
char **stringO = (char**) malloc (sizeof(char*));
char stringOne[17] = "a" ;
char stringTwo[17] = "b";
char stringThree[17] = "c";
char newStr[17] = "d";

*stringO = stringOne;
strcpy(*stringO, newStr);
```

If I have to use `stringO` the way you have allocated memory for it, then:

```
strcpy(*stringO, newStr);
strcpy(stringOne, *stringO);
```

Comment: @gta0004: I don't understand. What didn't work for you? See [this](http://ideone.com/vDdnQz) and [this](http://ideone.com/kBtw33).